# I want to upload the document in SharePoint online document library with content type

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react, react-webpart

My code -

```
sp.web
      .getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Student%20Details%20No%20Content%20Type")
      .files.add(fileContent.name, fileContent, true)
      .then(f => {
        f.file.getItem().then(item => {
          item.update({
            Title: "A Title",
            Description: "My Other Value"
          });
        });
      });
```

Type :

```
Choice
Site Content type
```

How to upload document with metadata .. like Choice and Site Content Type .

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I need to upload files along with data of a taxonomy and people field

Answer (score 0):

You can upload  document with metadata (Choice/Content Type) like below:

```
sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/s01/mytestdoclib").files.add(myfile.name, myfile, true).then(f => {  
        console.log("File Uploaded");  
        f.file.getItem().then(item => {  
            item.update({  
                Title: "Metadata Updated",
                ContentTypeId: "0x01030058FD86C279252341AB303852303E4DAF",
                ChoiceField: "Choice 3"
            }).then((myupdate) => {  
              console.log(myupdate);  
              console.log("Metadata Updated");  
            });  
        });  
    });
```

For multi select choice field(checkbox), it should be:

```
ChoiceField: {
      results: [ 'Choice #2', 'Choice #3' ]
    }
```

BR